# reactive to data.frame in shiny + DT

Tags: r, shiny, reactive, dt

I am struggling on handling a reactive object. I have created a reactive function to change a data.frame, however, I would like to calculate some measures after the reactive function.

My work so far:

UI code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
ui <- fluidPage(
  # App title ----
  titlePanel("CheckList"),
  sidebarLayout(
    
    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(width = 2,
                 uiOutput("codePanel"), 
                 uiOutput("varPanel") 
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      
      DT::dataTableOutput("text")
      
    )
  )
)
```

Server Code:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  df <- as.data.frame(cbind(matrix(round(runif(50, -1, 1), 3), 10), sample(0:1, 10, TRUE)))
  
  filt <- selectInput("codeInput",label ="filter1",
                      choices = as.list(unique(df$V6)), multiple = T, selected = 0)
  
  filt2 <- selectInput("varInput",label ="filter2",
                       choices = colnames(df[,-6]), multiple = T, selected = colnames(df[,-6]))
  
  output$codePanel <- renderUI({ filt
    
  })
  
  output$varPanel <- renderUI({ filt2
    
  })
  
  dat <- reactive({
    
    ab <- subset(df, V6 %in% input$codeInput) 
    ab <- ab[,-6]
    ab <- ab[, names(ab) %in% input$varInput] 
    
    
  })
  
 
  
  df1 <- as.data.frame(isolate(dat()))
  
  vals <- reactiveValues()
  vals$rm = mean(rowMeans(df1))
  vals$rr = range(df1)[2]-range(df1)[1]
  vals$r1 = abs(range(df1))[2] - mean(rowMeans(df1))
  vals$r0 = abs(range(df1))[1] - mean(rowMeans(df1))
  
}
```

My problem is trying to `isolate(dat()`and convert it to data.frame on:

```
  df1 <- as.data.frame(isolate(dat()))
```

The error message says "object of type 'closure' is not subsettable".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the cause of this error (and I get a different error when I run your code) but there is a couple of problems in your server code.

`input$codeInput` and `input$varInput` are `NULL` when the app starts, so you have to use `req`:

```
  dat <- reactive({
    req(input$codeInput, input$varInput)
    ab <- subset(df, V6 %in% input$codeInput) 
    ab <- ab[,-6]
    ab <- ab[, names(ab) %in% input$varInput] 
  })
```

You can't call `dat()` without a reactive context, as you do when you write `df1 <- as.data.frame(dat())`. You can define your reactive values `vals` as follows:

```
  vals <- reactiveValues()
  
  observe({
    vals$rm = mean(rowMeans(dat()))
    vals$rr = range(dat())[2]-range(dat())[1]
    vals$r1 = abs(range(dat()))[2] - mean(rowMeans(dat()))
    vals$r0 = abs(range(dat()))[1] - mean(rowMeans(dat()))
  })
```

Note that I use `observe` because it is a reactive context, and that is required.